# Изменение типа столбца с зависимостями в БД

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-key

В нашем новомодном стартапе было принято решение перехода на uuid с хранением в строке. В базе надо было перевести в таблице тип данных столбца id с bigint на text. Но оказалось, таблицы, которые ссылаются на этот столбец, не дают этого сделать, мол мы ссылаемся на int, а не на text.Пришлось вместо миграции в 1 строчку изменения типа писать здоровую с удалением этих зависимых таблиц, только потем изменением типа, а потом заново с заведением "новых" отредактированных таблиц. Может есть какой-то более элегантный способ делать такие штуки?

Comment: Таблицы удалять не обязательно, надо удалить внешние ключи, поменять тип основной колонки, поменять типы колонок во всех таблицах и после этого заново создать внешние ключи

Comment: А по поводу uuid вы точно уверены что он вам нужен ? У вас какая то распределенная тема с рождением ключей в разных системах ? Он и так занимает 16 байт в виде uuid поля, а в тексте 36 байт. Не удивляйтесь потом почему таблица с парой полей с данными на 80 Мб занимает на диске 2 Гб и одна тормозит как будто 10 join к ней делаете (цифры взяты из реальной системы где лечили проблемы)

Comment: @Mike спасибо за совет, у нас банковская крипто-блокчейн-нейросеть с распределённым облачным вычислением и резервированием на raid 0, мой CTO сказал что без uuid вообще никак

Comment: Да, слово "распределенная" однозначно говорит что нужны uuid. Но если вы были готовы удалить таблицы, т.е. в них еще нет важных данных, задумайтесь что бы сделать поле по крайней мере типа UUID, что бы занимало 16 байт и хотя бы теоретически могло быть адекватно отсортировано. P.S. для генерации uuid посмотрите в сторону uuid6 или 7 (Если соображения "случайности" из мира криптографии не перевесят)

Comment: спасибо, если оформите как ответ, поставлю вам класс и зелёну галку

Comment: А как насчёт алгоритма Hi/Lo для генерации ключей?

Comment: По поводу способа делать такие штуки: [Evolutionary Database Design](https://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html) - пишут большие статьи и книги.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ, который могу предложить, если в таблицах уже есть данные, которые не хочется терять.

Создать в таблице, в которой хотим сменить тип ключа, ещё один ключ типа uuid (старые пока не удаляем) . И соответственно добавит foreign key, которые будут ссылаться уже на него. Затем старые foreign key и primary key удаляй (именно в таком порядке).

Но для перепривязки ключей надо конечно будет маленький скрипт написать.
Полностью таблицы в таком случае можно не удалять